# How can i cancel keycode backspace in input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to cancel all keys in input, here is my code

```js
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.charCode && (event.charCode < 48 || event.charCode > 57 || event.charCode > 48)) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1" size="4" max="7" name="people-value" id="adults-value">
```

Why backspace still works for this? What more events I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the browser, but typically the `keypress` event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key is able to produce a character value.

Since backspace does not produce any output, it does not fire the keypress event.

You can, however, use the `keydown` event.

```js
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.charCode)
  if (event.charCode && (event.charCode < 48 || event.charCode > 57 || event.charCode > 48)) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1" size="4" max="7" name="people-value" id="adults-value">
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L47k7uwx/1/**